# Spring MVC: Multiple dataSources: select DB schema based on user selection from UI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I'm working on a web app which works fine. But recently from management request we need to serve our web app to multiple teams. So what we decided is to create a separate copy of DB schema for each team.

Let's say our team uses TEAM_A schema & other team uses TEAM_B schema. Both DB schema's are exactly same only difference is data in them.

So I used [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) in my application like this:

```
package com.company.app.utils.datasource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DynamicDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
     protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
                 return TeamContextHolder.getTeamType();
             }
}
```

And TeamContextHolder as:

```
package com.company.app.utils.datasource;
public class TeamContextHolder{

    public static final String TEAM_A_DATA_SOURCE = "aTeamDataSource";
    public static final String TEAM_B_DATA_SOURCE = "bTeamDataSource";

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setTeamType(String teamType) {
        contextHolder.set(teamType);
    }

    public static String getTeamType() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearTeamType() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

Spring configuration file have below bean definition for data-sources:

```
 <bean id="aTeamDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost.com:3306/TEAM_A?autoReconnect=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="welcome" />
        <property name="password" value="welcome" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bTeamDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost.com:3306/TEAM_B?autoReconnect=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="welcome" />
        <property name="password" value="welcome" />
    </bean>

    <bean primary="true" id="dynamicDataSource" class="com.company.app.utils.datasource.DynamicDataSource" >
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map key-type="java.lang.String">
                <entry value-ref="aTeamDataSource" key="aTeamDataSource"></entry>
                <entry value-ref="bTeamDataSource" key="bTeamDataSource"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="aTeamDataSource" >
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My home controller:

```
package com.company.app.web;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("team")
public class Home {

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Home.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public ModelAndView mainHomePage() {
        logger.info("Landing on main home page");
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        return new ModelAndView("/home", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/setteam")
    public ModelAndView rememberTeam(@RequestParam String product) {
        logger.info("Setting product info: " + product);
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("team", team);
        return new ModelAndView("/home", "model", model);
    }

}
```

From home controller, I'm passing team session variable to other controllers via JSP file.

My home.jsp has below form:

```
<form action="./setproduct" method="POST" class="p-a-4">
    <fieldset class="page-signup-form-group form-group form-group-lg">
    <select class="page-signup-form-control form-control" id="grid-input-lg-2" name="product">
        <option value="Not selected">Not selected</option>
        <option value="TEAM_A">TEAM_A</option>
        <option value="TEAM_B">TEAM_B</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary m-t-3">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then finally I'm setting datasource to use in my DaoImpl classes as:

```
if (filters.getTeam().equalsIgnoreCase("TEAM_B")){ 
    TeamContextHolder.setTeamType(TeamContextHolder.TEAM_B_DATA_SOURCE);
}
```

And it works as expected as I thought. But blown in production as all the time TEAM_B datasource is selected.

So my questions:

1. Is it possible the on single tomcat webserver (where we deployed our
   app) few users can select TEAM_A and work with TEAM_A_DATA_SOURCE
   and few users select TEAM_B and work with TEAM_B_DATA_SOURCE?
   Initially I thought it is doable but after this kaboom on production
   I'm not sure if it's possible in spring.
2. If it's NOT possible then
   how should I handle my case where end users can select their teams
   and work simultaneous on two different DB schema's on same web-app.

Comment: One solution comes in my mind is: create one more instance of tomcat and deploy your war. Hence you will have 2 DBs two tomcat instance and two copy of single war

Comment: Thanks @UmeshKumarSharma but that way we basically will have our app hosted at two locations and user selection of team will NO be valid right. Basically at one tomcat instance we will connect to TEAM_A schema and at other we will connect to TEAM_B (means separate app URL for each team). Please correct me if this is NOT what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by changing contextHolder from ThreadLocal to HttpSession, that way I was able to connect to a team's DB schema for a entire browser session. Also now I don't have to pass session variable to other controllers and no need to set datasource to use in my DaoImpl classes as I was doing earlier. So now my updated TeamContextHolder looks like this:

```
package com.company.app.utils.datasource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class TeamContextHolder {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TeamContextHolder.class);

    public static HttpSession getCurrentSession() {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
    }

    public static void setTeamType(String teamType) {
        TeamContextHolder.getCurrentSession().setAttribute("team", teamType);
    }

    public static String getTeamType() {
        logger.info("Session attribute product: " + TeamContextHolder.getCurrentSession().getAttribute("team"));
        return (String) TeamContextHolder.getCurrentSession().getAttribute("team");
    }
}
```

Session variable is set from home controller as:

```
package com.company.app.web;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("team")
public class HomeController  {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/home")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        logger.info("Landing on main home page");
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        return new ModelAndView("/home", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/setteam")
    public ModelAndView setteam(@RequestParam String team,
                                        HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Setting session attribute:
        request.getSession().setAttribute("team", team);
        logger.info("Setting team: " + team);
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("team", team);
        return new ModelAndView("/home", "model", model);
    }

}
```

Comment: of course: *never* use `ThreadLocal` as "context holder", when it is about "session attributes", since `ThreadLocal` is "thread based" & which means (in tomcat/servlet environment) "request based". Sry for coming late :) (accept your answer!?;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple entity managers which will be scanning the different set of repositories and you can switch those entity managers depending upon your cookie.